Conjugation of Frobenius-like groups
Let $G,H < S_n$ and $\varphi \colon G \to H$ is a group isomorphism. Suppose that $\forall g \in G\setminus\{1\}$: $|fix(g)| \leq 1$ and $\forall h \in H\setminus\{1\}$: $|fix(h)| \leq 1$, where $fix(g) = \{i\in \overline{1,n} | g(i)=i\}$ - set of fixed points.
Question: are these groups conjugated?
First of all I tried to describe cycle structure of permutation. It easy to see that permutations in $G$ and $H$ have one of these cycle structures $[1^1,s^{\frac{n-1}{s}}]$ or $[s^{\frac{n}{s}}]$. Also it can be proved that $g$ and $\varphi(g)$ has the same cycle structure, so there exists an element $t\in S_n$ $\textbf{(which depends on g)}$ such that $\varphi(g) = t^{-1}gt$. It makes me wonder that $G$ and $H$ are conjugated...

The identity element $1$ is in $G$, but $|\text{fix}(1)| = n > 1$. Is there a typo in the setup of the question, or did I misunderstand something?

@angryavian, the question was edited. Of course it was meat that every nonidentity element has at most one fixed point!

@angryavian, May be we should consider a subgroup $K = {g\in G | fix(g) = \emptyset \text{ or } g=1}$. $K$ is normal subgroup in $G$. Does it have a compliment?

I think the actions of $G$ and $H$ on each of their orbits are either regular or an action as a Frobenius group, and there can be at most one Frobenius action. So the problem reduces to the case when both actions are transitive, and then yes, they are conjugate in $S_n$.

@DerekHolt, Why there can be at most one Frobenius action?

@DerekHolt, if $\Omega_i=i^{G}$ is an orbit of $G$ and $j^{H} = \Gamma_j$ is an orbit of $H$ why do the actions $G$ on $\Omega_i$ and $H$ on $\Gamma_j$ are conjugated (I mean that permutation groups on $\Omega_i$ and $\Gamma_j$ are conjugated)?

If there was more than one orbit with Frobenius action then elements in the Frobenius complement would fix more  than one point.

@DerekHolt,can you explain it in more detail, please?

@DerekHolt, if $n$ is odd we can take subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and expand it by involution $x \mapsto -x$, so we get Frobenius group on each orbit.

Your example is a Frobenius group on only one orbit and acts regularly on all other orbits.

The answer to this question is yes.
Note first that if a finite group $G$ is a Frobenius group then, by a well-known result of Thompson, the Frobenius kernel $K$ is nilpotent, and it is is not hard to see that $K$ is the Fitting subgroup of $G$, and all elements of $G$ outside of $K$ lie in a Frobenius complement, and there is a unique conjugacy class of such complements $H$. So the kernel and complements of $G$ are uniquely determined by $G$. (I think with a bit more work you can prove that without using Thompson's theorem.)
So now let $G \le S_n$ and suppose that all non-identity elements of $G$ fix at most one point. Then the action of $G$ on each of its orbits must be either regular or Frobenius. If there is a Frobenius orbit then, by the paragraph above, an element of $G$ fixes a unique point in that orbit if and only if it lies in the complement of the Frobenius kernel $K$. So there can be at most one Frobenius orbit, since otherwise the elements of $G \setminus K$ would fix more than one point.
So either $n = m|G|$ for some $m$ and all orbits of $G$ are regular, or $n = m|G| + |K|$ for some $m$ and there is a Frobenius orbit. We can tell which of the two cases we are in by the value of $n$ mod $|G|$. So if $H \le S_n$ with $H \cong G$, then the same applies to $H$.
So the problem reduces to proving that the regular actions of $G$ and $H$ are conjugate in $S_{|G|}$ and the Frobenius actions (if any) are conjugate in $S_{|K|}$. Since there is a unique conjugacy class of Frobenius complements (if any), this follows from the fact that the permutation actions of $G$ on the cosets of conjugate subgroups of $G$ are conjuagte.
